# Sql Query for values in two columns

Tags: sql, case

I have a student table.

```
Student_Name          Ethnicity1         Ethnicity2
============          ==========         ===========
A                     Asian              NZ European
B                     Indian             Asian
C                     NZ European
```

I want to write a SQL statement where I want to group them into two ethnicities only - Asian / non-Asian. I don't want to use the where clause.
So I have 700 students and I want to see the third column, where if the student's first ethnicity or second ethnicity is Asian then the third column should say Asian. something like this

```
Student_Name        Ethnicity1         Ethnicity2             Ethnicity 
===========         ==========         ==========             ========
A                     Asian             NZ European           Asian
B                     Indian            Asian                 Asian
C                     NZ European                             Non-Asian
```

Could anyone help, please?

Comment: You can try this `SELECT Student_Name,Ethnicity1,Ethnicity2, CASE WHEN Ethnicity1='Asian' OR Ethnicity2='Asian' then 'Asian' ELSE 'Non-Asian' as Asian_nonAsian FROM table; `

Comment: We need to see a list of all ethnicities along with whether each one be considered Asian or non Asian.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your logic you specify:

```
select t.*,
       (case when 'Asian' in (ethnicity1, ethnicity2) then 'Asian'
             else 'Non-Asian'
        end) as simplified_ethnicity
```

Answer (score 0):

Its rather a simple case statement, any how, if i understood ur question query might be

```
Select T.*, Case When T.Ethnicty1 In ('Asian', 'India') or T.Ethnicty2 In ('Asian', 'India') Then 'Asian' Else 'Non-Asian' End EthnicCity From Students T
```

Comment: Except that it would be better practice to maintain all ethnicities and the Asian/non Asian classification in a separate table.

Comment: ofcourse, it depends upon how good the data structures are, i could not understand need to have to columns for same purpose but rather discussing on structure, the solution was simple

Comment: There's an extra `c` in the alias used for your `CASE` statement